# How to configure additional CPU Governors on Ubuntu 22.04 with AMD p-state-epp Driver and GNOME 42.9?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, power-management, frequency, governor

I am running Ubuntu on the following platform:

```
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64 
Host: 82KV IdeaPad 3 17ALC6 
Kernel: 6.5.0-14-generic 
DE: GNOME 42.9 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 5500U with Radeon Graphics (12) @ 4.056GHz 
Memory: 17835MiB
```

Gnome Settings allows me to set CPU frequency governor to:

1. Performance
2. Balanced
3. Power Save

However, no matter what I do, that has no effect:

Using `cpufreq-info` I get the following:

```
>>cpufreq-info -d 
amd-pstate-epp

>>cpufreq-info -c 0
cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: amd-pstate-epp
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 4.06 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 4.06 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.40 GHz.
```

As you can see, the driver is AMD p-state driver, and there are only two governors, "powersave" and "performance"

Previously, I had the following governors:

- powersave
- schedutil
- ondemand
- performance

I suspect that during updating, the default driver was changed from whatever it was to "amd-pstate-epp", and maybe Gnome is not geared to this?

In any case, I would love to return to my previous configuration with above-mentioned 4 governors, or alternatively have Gnome to work with the three governor settings it supports.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR; not possible, the kernel's scaling driver dictates what is possible - and what not.

Longer version:
First of all, this is not a GNOME-related problem or problem related to any desktop environment. The CPU governor is set by the Linux Kernel. You seem to have a newer AMD CPU with Zen 2 or newer architecture, for which the Linux kernel uses the amd-pstate scaling driver. The addition eep means that the driver utilizes the more efficient power managed of the CPU.

The scaling driver also dictates which modes are available. Which is for modern CPUs - also applies to newer Core i CPUs from Intel - the two states you mention.

For modern CPUs like you have it is not recommended anyway to set any mode manually - while it made sense under certain circumstances for older (and more dumb) CPUs, the moderns ones have a very sophisticated power management built-in which offers efficient power saving and idle modes but at the same time deliver performance as necessary.
If you want to learn more about your scaling driver, see [Linux kernel documentation](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/pm/amd-pstate.html).

In case you feel any user space program or GUI-based program is something hiding from you, you can easily access the files within the **/sys** file system to see what the Linux Kernel used on you system offers. Go to `cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/` and run `ls` in this directory. You will see a couple of files with pretty self-explanatory names. Run `cat scaling_driver` to see which CPU driver is used by the kernel and `cat scaling_governor` to list the available scaling governors.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I guess I just have to do changes manually, which I also did previously with my own little shell script. I just have only two governors now.

Comment: After reading up using the link you provided to the kernel documentation it seems to me that the amd_pstate driver indeed should support governors such as chedutil, ondemand,  etc. So I am still confused.

Answer (score 0):

After the answer from "noisefloor" I looked into the link he provided and in
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/pm/amd-pstate.html, and based on that I experimented a little with kernel boot parameters in /etc/default/grub/

1. GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="amd_pstate=disable".  With this option acpi-cpufreq driver re-appeared and all governors did too.
2. GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="amd_pstate=guided".  With this option amd_pstate driver was back again, but now with all the governors as for acpi-cpufreq driver.

the parameter "amd_pstate=guided" is a socalled AMD Pstate Operation mode, which can attain the following values:

- active
- passive
- guided
- disabled

The link explain the different modes and their function.  The defaul on my host was "active", which only provided "powersave" and "performance" governors to switch among.  It is my understanding that "guided" means it takes guidance from one of the full set of governors available when using acpi_cpufreq driver.

Comment: Good that it works respectively the options you work looking for appeared again. It is may understanding that the acpi-cpufreq is kind of a fallback solution driver which generically works, but is less sophisticated when it comes to power saving modes. As far as I am aware the goal is to reach high C-states (the higher the C-state, the lower the power consumption while a core idles) as often as possible.